# Double loops for "concatenation of subarrays in bigger array"

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy, concatenation

I want to assemble several subarrays in a big array automaticly, "manually" it s that :

```
import numpy as np
blank = np.empty([4,4])


A = np.ones([2,2])
B = np.ones([2,2]) * 2
C = np.ones([2,2]) * 3
D = np.ones([2,2]) * 4


A3d = np.reshape(A,(1,A.shape[0],A.shape[1]))
B3d = np.reshape(B,(1,B.shape[0],B.shape[1]))
C3d = np.reshape(C,(1,C.shape[0],C.shape[1]))
D3d = np.reshape(D,(1,D.shape[0],D.shape[1]))


conc = np.concatenate((A3d,B3d,C3d,D3d), axis=0)

blank[0:2,0:2] = conc[0,:,:]
blank[0:2,2:4] = conc[1,:,:]
blank[2:4,0:2] = conc[2,:,:]
blank[2:4,2:4] = conc[3,:,:]
```

I try with a double loop for but it doesn t work...

```
blank = np.empty([4,4])

for j in range(blank.shape[0]/A.shape[0]):
    for i in range(blank.shape[0]/A.shape[0]):
            blank[0:A.shape[0],j*A.shape[0]:A.shape[0]*(j+1)] = conc[j,:,:]
```

Comment: On a line it seems to be ok but when we change of a column the result is different of expected... :/

Comment: perhaps i could use np.repeat to force to have coordinates...: for i in range(list(np.repeat(np.arange(0, blank.shape[0]/A.shape[0]),2))):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter way of making `conc`

```
conc = np.array([A,B,C,D])
```

you could concatenate the pieces in 2 steps to make `blank` directly

```
blank = np.vstack([np.hstack([A,B]),np.hstack([C,D])])
```

Is that still 'manual'?

Lets step back and look at `blank`:

```
In [65]: blank
Out[65]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.]])

In [66]: blank.flatten()
Out[66]: 
array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  3.,
        3.,  4.,  4.])
```

Often it is possible to assemble a large array of one concat followed by a reshape.  But

```
In [69]: conc.flatten()
Out[69]: 
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.,
        4.,  4.,  4.])
```

The data elements in `conc` are contiguous.  Those in `blank` are interspersed.  That's what makes constructing `blank` trickier.

Do the elements have to be arranged as in `blank`?  Why not?

```
In [82]: conc.reshape(4,4)
Out[82]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.]])
```

---

But to focus on the double iteration, let's try:

```
In [89]: for i in range(0,4,2):
   ....:     for j in range(0,4,2):
   ....:         print blank[i:i+2, j:j+2]
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]
[[ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
[[ 3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.]]
[[ 4.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.]]
```

That gives a clue as to how to construct the assignment

```
In [100]: conc2=conc.reshape(2,2,2,2)
In [101]: x=np.empty([4,4])
In [102]: for i in range(0,4,2):
    for j in range(0,4,2):
        x[i:i+2, j:j+2]=conc2[i/2,j/2]
   .....:         
In [103]: x
Out[103]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  4.,  4.]])
```

This can be cleaned up, but it is a start.

---

but back the stacking, here's a way with one iteration:

```
np.vstack([np.hstack(conc[i:i+2,...]) for i in range(0,4,2)])
```

Generalizing to other shapes:

```
In [149]: k,l,m,n = 3,4,2,3
In [150]: conc = np.array([np.ones([m,n],dtype=int)*i for i in range(k*l)])
In [151]: np.vstack([np.hstack(conc[i:i+l]) for i in range(0,k*l,l)]).shape
Out[151]: (6, 12)
```

Comment: Thanks for help ;) yep it s still manual i must assembly near of 1 thousand of subarrays! :s but i keep in mind hstack and vstack it could be useful :)

Comment: and i try reshape but as you can see, the values are not well positioned

Comment: I've generalized the stacking

Comment: Thanks for the double iteration i will try tomorrow, i must finish an another part tonight! Thanks again ;)